# Округление в запросе SQL

Tags: sql

Достаю из БД рейтинг игрока следующим запросом, где `S` - убийства, `D` - смерти

```
SELECT 
  'player_name', 
  IF(D = 0, S, (S / D)) AS 'rating' 
FROM
  accounts 
ORDER BY
  IF(D = 0, S, (S / D)) DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Как сделать округление вниз? К примеру `S` = 23, `D` = 4. Частное = 5.75. Нужно вывести 5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правило любая СУБД предоставляет функцию `FLOOR()`, которая округляет число "вниз"

```
SELECT 
  'player_name', 
  FLOOR(IF(D = 0, S, (S / D)) * 10) / 10 AS 'rating' 
FROM
  accounts 
ORDER BY
  IF(D = 0, S, (S / D)) DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Не все реализации поддерживают округление дробных. Для того, чтобы округлить до первого знака после запятой, обычно прибегают к такому приему: предварительно умножают число на 10, а после применения функции `FLOOR()` делят на 10.